# How to read function definition in PHP manual

Tags: php

I was going through the PHP documentation for this function below and trying to understand what [, before the 2nd parameter means?

```
string basename ( string $path [, string $suffix ] )
```

Why not simply mention it as below:

```
string basename ( string $path , string $suffix )
```

The above explanation should help me understand the below function definition:

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )
```

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) Means it is optional. This question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: `string` is variable type (int, string, bool, array, object), `$path, $suffix` is variable meaning. `[]` is optional parameter. `$delimiter = ","` means that `$delimiter` has default value = "," if it's not set.

Comment: @Rizier123 Reading language documentation is necessary for programming.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, but it's not realted with programming directly. Also there are good pages on the manual what everything means

Comment: Well, it's not something a normal reader of English would know, it's very tightly related to programming, although it's also used in manuals for CLI commands.

Comment: Yeah, I also think this belongs here. As other reasons said, a person (especially well developed) documentation is important.

Comment: @Barmar Something tells me, that OP didn't even put [their title into google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=How+to+read+function+definition+in+PHP+manual) which then gives you an answer in 0.33 seconds.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of SO questions I've answered simply by googling the title or the error message they got.

Comment: may be helpful: [PHP Manual: How to read a function definition prototype](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php). It mentions the 'optional parameter syntax'.

Comment: @Rizier123 Unfortunately I did try searching online but didn't get the right search result. While however posting on stackoverflow I came up with this title not knowing that the same search query will get me the best result. Everything seems obvious in hindsight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` just indicates that the argument is optional. In your example:

```
string basename ( string $path [, string $suffix ] )
```

This is a function `basename` which takes a `$path` argument and, optionally a `$suffix` argument. It returns a `string`.

There may also be an initial value set, as in your second example:

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )
```

In this case the `$length` argument is optional and the value `0` will be used if it is not supplied.

Comment: How is this question programming related? It's about how to understand php.net pages.

Comment: @Rizier123 isn't understanding `php.net` a good start for programming ? :)

Comment: @Random Yep, but by simply [reading](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) this question can be avoided

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes,  but if the OP doesn't know about the existence of that page, how will they find it? It's not that they can't read; it's that they don't know where to look for it.

Comment: Yes, the true answer to the question should be a link to the page you suggest, @Rizier123.

Comment: @Random And if OP doesn't know where to search/read why didn't they just put [their title into google](https://www.google.ch/search?q=How+to+read+function+definition+in+PHP+manual)

Comment: @Rizier123 Unfortunately, I think it is a loosing battle... since about half questions can be answered this way... :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Unfortunately I did try searching online but didn't get the right search result. While however posting on stackoverflow I came up with this title not knowing that the same search query will get me the best result. Everything seems obvious in hindsight!